# PSoC-59 pins span

Tags: microcontroller

I'm wondering what is the dimension between rows of pins of CYPRESS CY8CKIT-059 (marked at the picture in **red**).
I searched through many manuals and specifications, but I havent found this information. Do You know where I can check this dimension?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load your image into a program such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) and drag a select a region to measure the pixel ratio between the edge of the board and the on-center spacing of the pins.  Doing this you get 190 pixels and 160 pixels.  This is a ratio of 1.1875.

The scaled spacing using the board vertical dimension is: **0.95 / 1.1875 = 0.8"**

As a check, if you perform the same procedure on the image of the board shown below, you get 237 / 203 = 1.1675, which gives 0.813.  You would not expect the result to be as close with a photo, but this also shows that the dimension is likely 0.8".

[image]

You would expect this dimension to be a multiple of 0.1" so that the module can plug into a breadboard.

Comment: Just eye-balling the vertical column of five holes near the middle of the board I would say that you are correct. It looks like there is space for just one more hole between the vertical column and each of the horizontal rows, for a total of 9 pins vertically and a space of 0.8 inches. Good answer!

Comment: @ElliotAnderson , Good observation

Comment: @crj11 Downloaded the layout files, you are 100% correct.

Comment: @awjlogan , Good idea to download the layout files.  Thanks for the verification.

Answer (score -1):

<del>It is 0.9" as PSOCs fit on Breadboards. The footprint is described in [this document][1] as:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
> Small Footprint: 3.0 x 1.2-Inch PCB and Standard 50-Pin, **0.9-Inch DIP Interface**</del>

I just measured a PSOC 5 I have. The correct spacing is 0.8"

Comment: I have added the image for quick ref.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same module as in the OP?

Comment: different module, same spacing

Comment: We have to ask...how can you be sure the different modules have the same spacing?

Comment: This is wrong - I've downloaded the layout file, and it's 0.8".

Comment: I just measured one. I'm wrong. It is 0.8".